# NPM-webshot : Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs

I'm trying to use the webshot module to load pages server-side, screenshot them and send them back to the browser as a PNG-file. I have however, encountered an error message that says:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I got this message while trying to compose some code based of the examples.

```
app.post('/api/downloadPng', function(req, res) {

     var renderStream = webshot('google.com');
     renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
       res.send(data)
     });
   });
```

I've come to the conclusion that since it's a stream, the module tries to send more data once it has already been opened, and node doesn't allow this.

So my question is: How can I trigger a function after Webshot is completely done with the rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`res.write`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) instead of the usual `res.send` since the former can be called multiple times for the same response. Just make sure to write the headers before start sending data:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.write(...);
res.write(...);
res.end();
```

Comment: Please give an example, including the writing of the headers.

Comment: If you open the link you'll see an example right below the documentation, StackOverflow is for help, not a place to ask for a solution